# putty network unreachable error help

Tags: putty

I am trying to run my raspberry pi by using putty but i keep getting network is unreachable. I have try[image] run it on other device it was working well

Comment: How do you configure putty? What's the destination address? Please take the short [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to get an idea how things work here.

Comment: if you are using port forwarding to reach the pi from outside your network, you cannot use that external address from inside your network, you should use the actual IP address of the pi.   if this doesnt help, give us more information to work with.  Are you on the same network when it works, when it doesnt? Can you ping it from the computer that wont connect via ssh?

Answer (score -1):

Have you activated the SSH Server on the Raspberry Pi?
You can do so by going to the terminal and typing `raspi-config` -> `Interfacing options` -> `SSH` and selecting `yes`.

Why did you use the public IP address? Just use the local IP address to access your Raspberry Pi, unless you have port forwarding setup for your Raspberry Pi.

Comment: op said it worked from another machine, so ssh is enabled

Comment: thank you sir but I have finally fix it. it was due to the Ethernet setting on my computer// properties > sharing > tick the options

Comment: Glad you found a solution. You can answer your question and mark it as solved.